# Script for Forgot Password

Tags: php, mysql

I have made Forgot Password script where the user will be redirected to another page & he needs to enter his email id. If email id is present then send the details to that particular email id. If not then give error message.Not able to get error message if email field is empty & submit is pressed

Please Help!

```
<?php 
$email="";
$emailErr="";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) 
            {
                $emailErr = "Email is required";
            } 
    else 
            {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                // check if e-mail address is well-formed
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
                    {
                        $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
                    }
            }
    if($_POST['submit']=='Send')
    {
            $host="localhost"; // Host name 
                        $username="root"; // Mysql username 
                    $password=""; // Mysql password 
                    $db_name="testmra"; // Database name 
                    // Connect to server and select databse.
                    $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 
                    mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
                    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);             
            $query="select * from newuser where emailid='$email'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Error: Cannot connect to db' );
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
            {
                $subject="Testing"; 
                $message="Hello Testing";
                mail($email, $subject, $message);

            }
            else
            {
                $emailErr = "No user exist with this email id";
            }
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head><title>MRA</title></head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<table align="center">
<tr><td align="right">Email Id :</td><td><input type="text" name="email"  value="<?php if (isset($_POST["email"])) { echo $_POST["email"];}?>"></td><td align="left"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><font color="red"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error you gave, change this line

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from newuser where emailid='$email'");
```

To this:

```
$query="select * from newuser where emailid='$email'";
```

I am assuming thats line 31... The query has to be a string, not an object.

Comment: Thanks!. It Worked. I tried to submit without entering the email id in the field but the error message it is giving is for No email id match where it should give that email id field is blank

Comment: I'm glad, accepting this as the answer wont hurt...

Comment: What can i do to get error message as per requirement

Comment: To get the correct solution, give a clear description of the problem and what you have tried so far. You may get many useful but irrelevant answers

Comment: i'd recomend you select only the needed fields from the database     `SELECT username, password FROM newuser WHERE emailid = '.$email.'`

Comment: Ok.. Now that it is checking for email id in db & giving error message as required. Only thing which is not working is if i leave the field empty & hit the Send button then it should give me error message as "Email is required" but instead of that it is giving "No user exist with this email id" ..What could be the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78769/discussion-between-platinum-industries-and-ankit).

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a link to user with a random token like example.com/reset_password?token=wecmwkwc321k3m1k2, save the token temporarily in db and when user hit the link match tokens and send user to the page that resets passwords...

Comment: But i don't want him to reset the password. I want this to be used only for registered user's. If the email id is matched then it will send details for that particular user only.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change your connection from:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
```

to:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name) or die("cannot connect");
```

Than change query from:

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from newuser where emailid='$email'");
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Error: Cannot connect to db' );
```

to:

```
$query=mysqli_query("select * from newuser where emailid='$email'", $conn) or die('Error: Cannot connect to db' );
```

Comment: What difference it will make ?

Comment: Mysqli connection take four params with db name.

Comment: Accepted! I did it in 2 lines

Comment: For query no need to call again mysqli_query(). Only one time with string query will give you results.